# call batch file from another passing parameters

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the following batch file that when run asks the user for input. This works fine.

```
@REM Sample batch file
SET PARAM1=""
SET PARAM2=""
SET /P PARAM1=Enter param1: %=%
SET /P PARAM2=Enter param2: %=%
@REM Process the params
```

I want to be able now to call this batch file from another and pass the parameters values to the above batch file, and the user wont be asked for input. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I believe you want something like this?

```
@echo off

:: Fetch param1
set "param1=%~1"
goto :param1Check
:param1Prompt
set /p "param1=Enter parameter 1: "
:param1Check
if "%param1%"=="" goto :param1Prompt

:: Fetch param2    
set "param2=%~2"
goto :param2Check
:param2Prompt
set /p "param2=Enter parameter 2: "
:param2Check
if "%param2%"=="" goto :param2Prompt

:: Process the params
echo param1=%param1%
echo param2=%param2%
```

Test.bat run without arguments:

```
>>test.bat
Enter parameter 1: foo
Enter parameter 2: bar
param1=foo
param2=bar
```

Test.bat run with arguments:

```
>>test.bat foo bar
param1=foo
param2=bar
```

---

Alternative, using environment variables instead of command line arguments (see also [ppumkin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883500/call-batch-file-from-another-passing-parameters/5883548#5883548)):

```
@echo off  

:: Fetch param1  
**set "param1=%globalparam1%"**  
goto :param1Check  
:param1Prompt  
set /p "param1=Enter parameter 1: "  
:param1Check  
if "%param1%"=="" goto :param1Prompt  

:: Fetch param2    
**set "param2=%globalparam2%"**  
goto :param2Check  
:param2Prompt  
set /p "param2=Enter parameter 2: "  
:param2Check  
if "%param2%"=="" goto :param2Prompt  

:: Process the params  
echo param1=%param1%  
echo param2=%param2%
```

Just set the environment variables `globalparam1` and `globalparam2` in your environment or your calling batch file to suppress the prompting:

Test.bat run without setting environment variables:

```
>>test.bat
Enter parameter 1: foo
Enter parameter 2: bar
param1=foo
param2=bar
```

Test.bat run with setting environment variables:

```
>>set globalparam1=foo

>>set globalparam2=bar

>>test
param1=foo
param2=bar
```

Note: setting the environment variables can also be done in e.g. a calling batch script.

Comment: This is great -but the question was how to set global variables from  in another batch so that if he runs completely different batch can pick them up from the global environment based on the sample code. was it not?

Comment: Above is my answer to the question, according to my understanding of what the OP wants, given the formulation of the question and the comments on the other answers… The batch file "*can be called on its own where [I] get asked for the params*" while maintaining the ability to "*call this batch file from another and pass the parameters values to the above batch file, and the user wont be asked for input*"

Comment: @ppumkin: You can call my batch file from another and pass the parameters on the `call` line. Your approach seems to be to call the batch file from another and pass the parameters by setting environment variables. This is also a valid approach, mine is just an alternative I like to use and propose.

Comment: Well the very last code bit is doing exactly that. calling an environment variable set inside another batch file. OK- so i didn't make a way to accept passed variables.. but that was not the scope of the question.. so why was my answer removed as correct?

Comment: @ppumkin: Ask the OP if you wish, I did not do anything about that except for posting my own answer :]

Comment: Good answer. Another nice extension is to perform customised actions depending on the entered/passed parameter like this `if "%param1%"=="foo" goto :doFoo`, etc.

Comment: I believe one can even just do `goto :doAction%param1%` (it's been a while, though), but that's not really the topic here

Answer (score 13):

In `main.cmd`:

```
set param1=%~1
set param2=%~2
echo %param1% - %param2%
```

In `caller.cmd`:

```
call main.cmd hello world
```

Output:

```
hello - world
```

[Reference for batch script parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Comment: but i want to be able to call main.bat file on its own also where I get asked for the params, is this possible?

Comment: asked? like in the batch asks what parameters you want to pass to itself?

Comment: right - so you want to call this batch file that asks questions from inside another batch and then the 2nd batch must pass back the variables to the already running batch.. I am sorry but I don't fully understand the question maybe.

Answer (score 5):

caller.bat /.cmd

```
@echo off
cls
set vara="Hello There"
set varb=67890

echo Variables set in caller.bat:
echo %vara%
echo %varb%

echo Calling passTo.bat
call passTo.bat %vara% %varb%
```

passTo.bat /.cmd

```
@echo off
echo.
echo Inside passTo.bat
set vara=%1
set varb=%2

echo vara: %vara%
echo varb: %varb%
```

Calling passTo.bat on its own from dos or command windows or any other application/shortcut

```
call passTo.bat PARAM1 PARAM2
```

---

Using the set Variables from caller.bat inside another batch

```
@echo off
echo.
echo Inside another.bat
echo -- You can start another batch here that sets the environment variables

set varOne=%vara% <- This gets the Environments Variable set in the nested batch bat using SET
set varTwo=%varb%

echo vara: %varOne% 
echo Is the same as
echo %vara%

echo varb: %varTwo%
echo is again the same as
echo %varb$
```

You might have to use SETX

Comment: but i want to be able to call passTo.bat file on its own also where I get asked for the params, is this possible?

Comment: like that- calling environment variables set by another batch?

Comment: shouldn't it write echo %varb% instead of eacho %varb$ ?